# Website is not loading on MAMP

Tags: xampp, mamp

I was developing website in my school's lab where XAMPP is installed, and everything was working properly. But now I'm facing need to work on my mac. I have installed the latest version of MAMP 2.0, and my website is not working properly on it. It is only loading half of the page, seems that at some point it stops compiling the page.
At first I thought it's database connection issue, but no, the connection strings are correct. I have tried configuring php.ini,  put error_reporting to E_ALL and reinstalled MAMP, but still no luck.
Wondering what can be the issue that is causing this situation... If you have any idea please share...

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the correct INI file? Check the output of `echo php_ini_loaded_file();` and edit that file. You can also enable error reporting from within the script using `ini_set`. Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks Amad. This vas very helpful, i've managed to find to error. I've found out that MAMP doesn't compile directories that are separated with backslash, because for Unix forwardslash is common notation. That was causing page not to load properly.